# How to add text with geom_text over geom_bars?

Tags: r, geom-text

I would like to add names of the questions over the bars that represent the anserws

[image]

Problem is that the text comes twice on to the bars. The blue and orange (fill) represent first and second evaluation, but they represent the same question. So what I would like to do is that the text (question) would only be printed once since the same question is asked in both evaluations and that the position would adjustable. How would I achieve this with the geom_text? Another way I thought was that the scale_x_discrete would be positioned differently, but I figured it can only be positioned to top, bottom, left or right.

```
plot_data <- structure(list(kunta = c("Kau", "Kau", "Kau", "Kau", "Kau", "Kau", 
"Kau", "Kau"), Arviointi = c("Ensimmäinen arviointi", "Ensimmäinen arviointi", 
"Ensimmäinen arviointi", "Ensimmäinen arviointi", "Toinen arviointi", 
"Toinen arviointi", "Toinen arviointi", "Toinen arviointi"), 
    Mittari = c("onn", "pkm", "tyy", "yk", "onn", "pkm", "tyy", 
    "yk"), value = c(0.935483870967742, 0.90625, 0.75, 0.161290322580645, 
    0.972972972972973, 0.794871794871795, 0.769230769230769, 
    0.027027027027027), Kansallinen = c(0.909396809571286, 0.754092238750233, 
    0.697411911443717, 0.116863721219664, 0.919229103508012, 
    0.819420873992363, 0.727938834023574, 0.0934428000432105)), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, y = value, fill = Arviointi)) +
   geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45, alpha = 1) +
   geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = Kansallinen, ymax = Kansallinen, group = Arviointi,           
   width  = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +    
   geom_text(aes(group = Mittari, label = ("text here")), hjust=-0.5, colour = "black", position = "dodge") +
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
   scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
   theme_minimal() +
   coord_flip() +
   scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100),
                     minor_breaks = NULL) +
   scale_x_discrete(labels = custom_labels ) +  # Apply custom labels to the x-axis
   labs(y = " ", x= " ")
```

Comment: Please provide the sample dataset to make the question reproducible. You may use `dput()` for that

Comment: Sure, sorry Im new to this page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this (you need to set `, position = position_dodge2(0.45)` and `group = Arviointi,` in its `aes()`):

You may use this:

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, y = value, fill = Arviointi)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45, alpha = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = Kansallinen, ymax = Kansallinen, group = Arviointi,           
                                      width  = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +    
  geom_text(aes(group = Arviointi, label = ("text here")), hjust=-0.5, colour = "black", position = position_dodge2(0.45, reverse = TRUE)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100),
                     minor_breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = paste0("custom_labels",1:4) ) +  # Apply custom labels to the x-axis
  labs(y = " ", x= " ")
```

[image]

**EARLIER ANSWER (before Q edit)**

```
ggplot(plot_data, aes(y = Mittari, x = value, group = Arviointi, fill = Arviointi)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE), width = 0.45, alpha = 1) +
  geom_errorbar(data = plot_data, aes(x = Mittari, ymin = Kansallinen, ymax = Kansallinen, group = Arviointi,           
                                      width  = 0.45), position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE)) +    
  geom_text(aes(group = Arviointi, label = label), hjust=-0.5, colour = "black", position = position_dodge2(reverse = TRUE, 0.45)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("steelblue", "darkorange")) +
  theme_minimal() +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent_format(scale = 100),
                     minor_breaks = NULL) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = "custom_labels" ) +  # Apply custom labels to the x-axis
  labs(y = " ", x= " ")
```

[image]

Used data:

```
plot_data <- data.frame(Mittari = c(20,5,58,60,70,62,75,80)/100,
                        value = rep(4:1, each = 2),
                        Arviointi = rep(c("A","B"), times = 4),
                        Kansallinen = rnorm(n = 8) + 1,
                        label = rep(c("text here A", "text here B"), 4)
                        )
```

Comment: @Roni Please see my edit made upon your data structure having been presented. Pay atetention to `group` `aes()` and `position_dodge()`

Comment: Thanks that helped, also by adding to y-coordinate to the geom_text I got them aligned perfectly.